# Assig value to a variable if it is empty

Tags: php, if-statement, get

I have the following variable that I get it from url:

```
$getdeparture = $_GET["departure"];
```

I want to assign a value if it is posted empty  &departure=

Comment: if(empty($getdeparture) ) // do stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that?

```
$getdeparture = isset($_GET["departure"]) ? $_GET["departure"] : $your_value;
```

or

```
$getdeparture = !empty($_GET["departure"]) ? $_GET["departure"] : $your_value;
```

or

```
$getdeparture = isset($_GET["departure"]) && !empty($_GET["departure"])  ? $_GET["departure"] : $your_value;
```

Missed `!` in-front of empty the first time.

Comment: No problem, you should start accepting answers for your questions. Otherwise people would stop helping you.